# Graph API working in ASP.Net, but DLL assembly error in Windows service

Tags: asp.net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, windows-services

I have an ASP.Net application which uses the Microsoft Graph API (Nuget packages Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Identity.Client). The application has two execution modes. In one mode it will run the Graph API calls in the ASP.Net web context. In its other mode, it offloads the process to a Windows service running on the same server, with ASP.Net calling the service asynchronously.

The Graph API calls are working fine in ASP.Net, but when I go to test the Windows service, I'm getting DLL load errors.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

The relevant Nuget package versions are:

- Microsoft.Graph: 4.3.0
- Microsoft.Graph.Core: 2.0.4.0

The windows service executes up to the point where it instantiates the class that contains the Graph service client. Then it goes looking for Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.3.0 and throws an exception because the only version available is 2.0.4.0.

I don't know why it's looking for 2.0.3.0. I can't find any reference to 2.0.3.0 anywhere in my project.

It might be worth mentioning that as a post build step I'm copying the Windows service .exe and all .dll files in the service project "bin" folder to a separate folder that the service executes from. I'm wondering if this is the cause of the problem, and there's some other dll that Asp.Net can access, but isn't being copied to the bin folder. I still don't know why the Windows service tries to load an old copy of the dll instead of using the version installed by Nuget.

**To summerise:**

- Asp.Net correctly runs with dll version 2.0.4.0
- Windows service fails to load after trying to access 2.0.3.0, which it doesn't have
- Both Asp.Net and Windows service are running exactly the same code base. Neither are configured in Nuget to have a dependency on Graph. They both reference a separate project that has the Graph dependencies.
- Asp.Net loads the dll at the same point in the code as the Windows service, but the logs indicate its plucking the dll out of the ASP.Net temporary files in C:\windows. The version it pulls is still 2.0.4.0 though, so I don't see any issues here.

Been stuck on this one for several hours. Are there any tools for analysing DLL issues in .Net? I want to know what's trying to access version 2.0.3.0 and why.

**Edit:**

Here's the assembly binding info. It looks like the service might be ignoring my app.config file for some reason, as it says "no application configuration file found". If that's the case, then it would be ignoring the binding redirect telling it to use v2.0.4.0.

> FusionLog "=== Pre-bind state information ===\r\n     LOG: DisplayName =
> Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\n (Fully-specified)\r\n   LOG: Appbase
> = file:///C:/inetpub/SurewayImsDev/ImsServiceBin/\r\n     LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL\r\n     Calling assembly : Microsoft.Graph,
> Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.\r\n
> ===\r\n     LOG: This bind starts in default load context.\r\n  LOG: No
> application configuration file found.\r\n     LOG: Using host
> configuration file: \r\n  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.\r\n
> LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=2.0.3.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\n  LOG: Attempting
> download of new URL
> file:///C:/inetpub/SurewayImsDev/ImsServiceBin/Microsoft.Graph.Core.DLL.\r\n
> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build
> Number\r\n    ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr =
> 0x80131040). Probing terminated.\r\n"     string

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was I hadn't copied the app.config files over. This was causing the windows service to run without knowing how to map the dll files. All working now.